# Generate an array of checkbox values and post the array to a function controller in Yii

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, yii

I have changed my question,I have a page where I have a list of check boxes independent of model. I want to get the values of the selected checkboxes and post the values of the checkbox to a function in controller. this Function is also independent of model.

**View**

This is in for loop.

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="student[]" value="<?php $esid=$examstudent[$i]['id']; ?>">
 </td>
```

Link

```
   echo CHtml::button('Allocate', array('submit' => array('ExamStudent/AddMod')));
```

**controller**

```
   public function actionAddMod()
  {
     $list=array(); 
$list[]=$_POST["student"];
print_r($list);
   }
```

when the link directing to the function is clicked, I want to send the data from "student" to the function in controller. How to go about it?

Comment: your code looks ok. What is not working at you?

Comment: @Stalinko : I'm getting an empty array when I print_r($list);

Comment: then you do something wrong somewhere else in the code. Check that you send POST and not GET. Try network tab in browser debug-tool (F12).

Comment: @Stalinko: Yea, I have been trying that and it directs me to function properly. Here I have added few more pieces to the puzzle. :-/

Comment: Now all is clear. It is just a link. It is not submit-button. You should send form using submit button. Use either "CHtml::submitButton()" or "CHtml::linkButton()"

Comment: @Stalinko: I tried that. `echo CHtml::button('Allocate', array('submit' => array('ExamStudent/AddMod')));` It gives me an error -- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submitForm' of undefined "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48568/discussion-between-stalinko-and-user983983)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have

```
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" name="student[]" value="<?php $esid=$examstudent[$i]['id']; ?>">
</td>
```

And what do you mean by redirect the Data to different page ?

Comment: I meant, I want to send data from "student" variable to xyz.php from abc.php

Comment: If you are using actual page redirect then save data in session, or else if this xyz.php is just used as partial view file then use render function to load this view file and pass data to this render function as parameter.

Comment: I'm redirecting it to a new page. Actually, I'm unable to post the data to my controller. Data from the "student" is not getting posted in controller of abc.php.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about why you wanna do this,

but you can use session to keep POST data;